# Scrolling backgrounds without tiles

Tags: 2d, tiles, scrolling

I'm writing a paper on game backgrounds and need to look at how they are implemented in different games, but I'm a bit stuck on scrolling backgrounds.

While it's easy to recognize a scrolling background, everywhere I look I also see tiles.

Are there any popular published games that use scrolling backgrounds, but that don't use tiles?

All of the classics, like Commander Keen, Mario, etc. use both scrolling and tiles.

Any suggestions? Google is not helping me on this one.

Comment: I'm not sure that a question like "List games that do X" is on-topic here, if you want to implement such a feature in one of your games, it would be more on-topic.

Comment: Perhaps you could rephrase your question to 'why are scrolling backgrounds implemented using tiles?' (which would fit in the 'subjective' question type see: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic )